# How to get all the related fields from a query set in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have two models, `Session` and `SessionType` which have a many-to-one relationship. There is also a `Family` foreign key on `Session`, like so:

```
from django.db import models


class SesssionType(models.Model):
    pass


class Session(models.Model):
    session_type = models.ForeignKey('SessionType')
    family = models.ForeignKey('Family')
```

For a certain instance `family` of `Family`, I have several `Session` objects in the `session_set`:

```
ipdb> family.session_set.all()
<QuerySet [<Session: Welcome>, <Session: Breastfeeding Preparation - Timothy Anderson>, <Session: First-Time Parents: The Basics of Birth>, <Session: Initial Postpartum Lactation>, <Session: Sleep Techniques for New Babies>, <Session: Breastfeeding Preparation>, <Session: Newborn Care Basics>, <Session: Easing the Transition Back to Work>, <Session: Preparing for Parenting>, <Session: Decoding Baby Cues>, <Session: Postpartum Doula Support>, <Session: First-Time Parents: Birth Prep Q&A>, <Session: Postpartum Lactation Follow-Up>, <Session: Sleep Training for 4 Months & Beyond>, <Session: Mental Wellness in Pregnancy>, <Session: Infant CPR>, <Session: Prenatal Pelvic Physical Therapy>, <Session: Prenatal Massage>]>
```

I would like to get a queryset containing the `SessionType`s of these `Session`s, similar to the following list:

```
ipdb> [session.session_type for session in family.session_set.all()]
[<SessionType: Welcome>, <SessionType: Breastfeeding Preparation>, <SessionType: First-Time Parents: The Basics of Birth>, <SessionType: Initial Postpartum Lactation>, <SessionType: Sleep Techniques for New Babies>, <SessionType: Breastfeeding Preparation>, <SessionType: Newborn Care Basics>, <SessionType: Easing the Transition Back to Work>, <SessionType: Preparing for Parenting>, <SessionType: Decoding Baby Cues>, <SessionType: Postpartum Doula Support>, <SessionType: First-Time Parents: Birth Prep Q&A>, <SessionType: Postpartum Lactation Follow-Up>, <SessionType: Sleep Training for 4 Months & Beyond>, <SessionType: Mental Wellness in Pregnancy>, <SessionType: Infant CPR>, <SessionType: Prenatal Pelvic Physical Therapy>, <SessionType: Prenatal Massage>]
```

It seems like the [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) method is meant for this, but calling it doesn't produce the desired result:

```
ipdb> family.session_set.select_related('session_type')
<QuerySet [<Session: Welcome>, <Session: Breastfeeding Preparation - Timothy Anderson>, <Session: First-Time Parents: The Basics of Birth>, <Session: Initial Postpartum Lactation>, <Session: Sleep Techniques for New Babies>, <Session: Breastfeeding Preparation>, <Session: Newborn Care Basics>, <Session: Easing the Transition Back to Work>, <Session: Preparing for Parenting>, <Session: Decoding Baby Cues>, <Session: Postpartum Doula Support>, <Session: First-Time Parents: Birth Prep Q&A>, <Session: Postpartum Lactation Follow-Up>, <Session: Sleep Training for 4 Months & Beyond>, <Session: Mental Wellness in Pregnancy>, <Session: Infant CPR>, <Session: Prenatal Pelvic Physical Therapy>, <Session: Prenatal Massage>]>
```

As seen above, the call to `select_related()` produced a query set with `Session` objects, and not `SessionType` objects. How can I get the `SessionType` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you say you can use new query set to select all `SessionType` objects.

but `select_related` usage is different

according to Django documentation and all I used select_related not change queryset object type. but only select all related objects from database by one query. for example see this query:

```
for item in family.session_set.select_related('session_type').all():
     print item.session_type
```

hits database once but when you write this:

```
for item in family.session_set.all():
     print item.session_type
```

for every print one database hit occurred and one database hit for base query occurred. its not important for little data but when your data is too large your site went slow without select_related. but be aware of using it. if you use it too much the action is opposite and your site went slow.

see more on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this problem by filtering all `SessionType` objects, like so:

```
ipdb> SessionType.objects.filter(session__family=family).order_by('session__session_number')
<QuerySet [<SessionType: Welcome>, <SessionType: First-Time Parents: The Basics of Birth>, <SessionType: Initial Postpartum Lactation>, <SessionType: Sleep Techniques for New Babies>, <SessionType: Breastfeeding Preparation>, <SessionType: Newborn Care Basics>, <SessionType: Easing the Transition Back to Work>, <SessionType: Preparing for Parenting>, <SessionType: Decoding Baby Cues>, <SessionType: Postpartum Doula Support>, <SessionType: First-Time Parents: Birth Prep Q&A>, <SessionType: Postpartum Lactation Follow-Up>, <SessionType: Sleep Training for 4 Months & Beyond>, <SessionType: Mental Wellness in Pregnancy>, <SessionType: Infant CPR>, <SessionType: Prenatal Pelvic Physical Therapy>, <SessionType: Prenatal Massage>]>
```

However, I have an inkling that this is less efficient than just getting the corresponding `session_type` from the `Session` objects in the `family.session_set`, so explanations as to why `select_related()` is not working as expected are still most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Do the query to get all the sessions for a family but only ask for the 'session_type' value to be returned rather than all the data for each session.

Once you have only the session_types returned, you can then use distinct() to get that response boiled down to only a list of the unique values.

```
family.session_set.all().values('session_type').distinct()
```